# Single DLL replacement in .NET Web Applications

Tags: .net, patch

We all know that it's often possible (ignoring any signature changes) to drop in replacement DLLs into webservers to update particular elements of a .NET Web Application.

I've always been extremely nervous about doing this as it can create hybrid versions and lead to more instability. However with more modern techniques (such as coding to interfaces and IoC) this impact can be reduced.

Assuming the code is stable is the DLL replacement a supported feature of the .NET framework which we all use or is it a hack which we're all exploiting?

Comment: When you change dll with new one - you need to restart your web application or any application. IoC usually create full application's object graph when application starts - so you need to restart it there too. It is not a hack - replacing dll - is so called "update"

Comment: @Fabio I usually update the web.config, my question isn't really about whether it can be done technically - it's about whether this DLL patching to create hybrid versions is considered a good idea

Comment: updating web.config will be not enough in cases when updated dll already in use(loaded in memory).